# Inject private field to tested method

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

Simple question, I have a class with have a List field with Items, I have a method operating on that List, checking if there is a Item with a name given in parameter and returning true or false. I would like to test that method, creating an ArrayList in test class, mocking JdbcItemDao class, and calling a method. Method in test cannot reach an array, how to fix it? Code:

```
     public class JdbcItemDao {
     private List<Item> tempStockList;

    public JdbcItemDao() {

    this.tempStockList = getAllStockItems();

   //getting items from my sql, returning them as ArrayList

}

  public boolean checkStockItems(String itemName) {
    for (Item item : tempStockList) {
        if (item.getItemName().equalsIgnoreCase(itemName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}}
```

Test class:

```
public class JdbcTest {


JdbcItemDao jdbcItemDao;
List<Item> tempStockList;

@Before
public void setup() {

    jdbcItemDao = mock(JdbcItemDao.class);
    tempStockList = new ArrayList<>();
    tempStockList.add(new Item(1, "LEDTv", new BigInteger("40"),
            new Integer("3"), new BigInteger("70")));

}


@Test
public void checkStockItemsName() throws Exception {

   assertTrue(jdbcItemDao.checkStockItems("LEDTv"));

}}
```

Comment: not sure you need to mock it.Is the getAllStockItems method that you do not want to invoke?

Comment: Never mock the class you are testing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot refactor i guess your left with creating a private class, overriding the method and using that class for testing:

```
public class JdbcTest {

   List<Item> tempStockList = new ArrayList<>();

   @Before
   public void setup() {

    tempStockList = new ArrayList<>();
    tempStockList.add(new Item(1, "LEDTv", new BigInteger("40"),
            new Integer("3"), new BigInteger("70")));

   }


   @Test
   public void checkStockItemsName() throws Exception {
     JdbcItemDao jdbcItemDao = new CustomJdbcItemDao();
     assertTrue(jdbcItemDao.checkStockItems("LEDTv"));

   }

   private class CustomJdbcItemDao extends JdbcItemDao{

      @Override
      public List<Item> getAllStockItems(){
        return tempStockList;
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the wrong kind of *test double*. You need a *spy* (which is a wrapper around the real implementation) instead of a *mock* (which is a subclass overriding all methods of the mocked class):

```
jdbcItemDao = spy(new JdbcItemDao());

tempStockList = new ArrayList<>();
tempStockList.add(new Item(1, "LEDTv", new BigInteger("40"),
        new Integer("3"), new BigInteger("70")));
doReturn(tempStockList).when(jdbcItemDao).getAllStockItems();
```

Off cause this only works if you move

```
this.tempStockList = getAllStockItems();
```

out of the constructor...

Answer (score 0):

There is a method 'getAllStockItems', it is in JdbcItemDao.java class

```
public List<Item> getAllStockItems() {
    return jdbcTemplate.query(SELECT_ALL_STOCK_ITEMS, itemRowMapper);
}
```

It is getting a data from MySQL database, so that's why i would like to use fake Array in tests.